# How to convert python dictionary file (having 2D array) in CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert a Python dictionary file (having 2D array) into CSV file.

My dict file looks like:

```
 data = {'t': array([0.0000e+00, 1.0000e-01, 2.0000e-01, ..., 2.9997e+03, 2.9998e+03,
       2.9999e+03]) * msecond, 
'v': array([[0.0000e+00, 1.0000e-01, 2.0000e-01, ..., 2.9997e+03, 2.9998e+03,
       2.9999e+03],[0.0000e+00, 1.0000e-01, 2.0000e-01, ..., 2.9997e+03, 2.9998e+03,
       2.9999e+03]]) * mV, 
'w': array([[0.0000e+00, 1.0000e-01, 2.0000e-01, ..., 2.9997e+03, 2.9998e+03,
       2.9999e+03],[0.0000e+00, 1.0000e-01, 2.0000e-01, ..., 2.9997e+03, 2.9998e+03,
       2.9999e+03]]) * mS}
```

Data have 2D array in the dictionary file. I saw some code related to it on Stack Overflow, something like this:

```
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, dict_data.keys())
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in dict_data:
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

This code gives an error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: here data is a python dictionary or it is stored in some file?

Comment: The error tells you that the `dict_data` variable is not a dictionary, but a string. How are you setting the `dict_data` variable?